# How to get claims from HttpOnly Cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js

I have an HttpOnly cookie that contains a username inside its ClaimTypes.Name

I know this by looking at the JWT cookie on jwt.io

I need to use that name inside a POST request I want to make.

How can I decode the HttpOnly cookie in NextJS / Javascript and get that username?

I have been trying the npm package 'cookie' to parse it but I can't seem to get it to work...

```
import cookie from 'cookie';

export default async (req, res) => {

  const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie);

   const username = cookies.cookie_name.value.name;  // undefined
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is what you have shown supposed to be client- or server-side JavaScript?

Comment: `Next.js is a minimalistic framework for server-rendered React applications as well as statically exported React apps.`

Comment: That would be the server-side portion. I could do it in the client side and sent it as a request there if required.

Comment: I don't think client side can access HttpOnly cookies right?

Comment: I just figured out that the HttpOnly cookie is encoded in base64 format. You have to decode the cookie. ```const cookieDecoded = decodeURI(cookies.cookie_name).trim();```